# Problema en el envió de datos en Ajax en un controlador Asp .Net

Tags: jquery, ajax, sql-server, asp.net

Tengo el siguiente problema, estoy tratando de enviar un sentencia `INSERT` a un controlador en ASP, pero al enviarlos por medio de JQuery, los datos llegan `Null` o en 0.

Mi procedimiento almacenado es el siguiente:

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[agregarIndicador]
     (
         @idCampo int,
         @categoriaIndicador int,
         @idContrato int,
         @campoPeriodo nvarchar(255) = '',
         @campoValor int
     )
     as
     begin 
     insert into Indicadores_SST(ID_CAMPO, CATEGORIA_INDICADOR, ID_CONTRATO, PERIODO, VALOR)
     values (@idCampo, @categoriaIndicador, @idContrato, @campoPeriodo, @campoValor)
     end
```

He tratado de verificado que no me hace falta ningún parámetro en el Web.Config el cual es el siguiente para para métodos Web:

```
<system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6" />
        <webServices>
          <protocols>
            <add name="HttpGet"/>
          </protocols>
        </webServices>
</system.web>
```

Este es mi codigo Jquery con una solicitud Ajax para el envio de información correspondiente a mi controlador en `MVC`:

```
'use strict';
$(document).ready(function () {
    var botonPrincipal = $("#nextBtn");
    botonPrincipal.click(function () {
        if (!$("#primeTab").css("display:block")) {
        /*Obtencion de los datos de los campos correspondiente a el primer modúlo*/
            var datosIndicadores = { };
            datosIndicadores.idCampo = $("#primeraTab #ID_CAMPO").val();
            datosIndicadores.categoriaIndicador = $("#primeraTab #CATEGORIA_INDICADOR").val();
            datosIndicadores.idContrato = $("#primeraTab #ID_CONTRATO").val();
            datosIndicadores.campoPeriodo = $("#primeraTab #PERIODO").val();
            datosIndicadores.campoValor = $("#primeraTab #VALOR").val();
            /*Fin de la obtencion de los datos de los campos correspondiente a el primer modúlo*/
            $.ajax({
                url: "/IndicadoresSST/PrimerIndicador",
                method: "POST",
                data: '{Ind:'+ JSON.stringify(datosIndicadores) +'}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                beforeSend: function () {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(datosIndicadores));
                    console.log("Enviando datos");
                },
                success: function (resultado, data) {
                    console.log(resultado);
                    console.log(data);
                    alert("Datos Ingresados de manera satisfactoria...")
                },
                error: function (err) { 
                    console.log(err);
                    console.log('Ocurrió un error al acceder a la información');
                },
                timeout: 2000
            });

        }
    })
});
```

Por último tenemos el controlador que ejecuta el procedimiento almacenado para insertar los datos:

```
[WebMethod]
            public void PrimerIndicador(IndicadorSST Ind)
            {
                string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SaricContext"].ConnectionString;
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("agregarIndicador", con);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter()
                    {
                        ParameterName = "@idCampo",
                        Value = Ind.ID_CAMPO
                    });
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter()
                    {
                        ParameterName = "@categoriaIndicador",
                        Value = Ind.CATEGORIA_INDICADOR
                    });
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter()
                    {
                        ParameterName = "@idContrato",
                        Value = Ind.ID_CONTRATO
                    });
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter()
                    {
                        ParameterName = "@campoPeriodo",
                        Value = Ind.PERIODO
                    });
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter()
                    {
                        ParameterName = "@campoValor",
                        Value = Ind.VALOR
                    });
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
```

Realmente no sé que este mal, ya que el `JSON` esta enviando los datos de manera correcta visto desde un `console.log`.

Mi modelo es el siguiente:

```
[Table("Indicadores_SST")]
    public class IndicadorSST
    {
        [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
        [Required]
        public int ID_INDICADOR_SST { get; set; }


        [ForeignKey("CampoIndicadorSST"),Column(Order = 1)]
        [Display(Name ="Campo Indicador")]
        public int ID_CAMPO { get; set; }


        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo Obligatorio")]
        [Display(Name = "Categoria Indicador")]
        [ForeignKey("CategoriaIndicadorSST"), Column(Order = 2)]
        public int CATEGORIA_INDICADOR { get; set; }


        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo Obligatorio")]
        [Display(Name = "Número De Contrato")]
        [ForeignKey("Contrato"), Column(Order = 3)]
        [Range(1,10000)]
        public int ID_CONTRATO { get; set; }

        //[Key, Column(Order = 4)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe Ingresar Un Periodo.")]
        [StringLength(255, ErrorMessage = "{0} la longitud debe estar entre {2} y {1}.", MinimumLength = 4)]
        [Display(Name = "Nombre Periodo")]
        public string PERIODO { get; set; }


        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe Ingresar Un Valor.")]
        [Range(1, 100000)]
        [Display(Name = "Valor")]
        public int VALOR { get; set; }


        public CampoIndicadorSST CampoIndicadorSST { get; set; }
        public CategoriaIndicadorSST CategoriaIndicadorSST { get; set; }
        public Contrato Contrato { get; set; }
```

Visto en `SQL` es de la queda de la siguiente manera:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Indicadores_SST](
    [ID_INDICADOR_SST] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ID_CAMPO] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CATEGORIA_INDICADOR] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ID_CONTRATO] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PERIODO] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [VALOR] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Indicadores_SST] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID_INDICADOR_SST] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Indicadores_SST]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Indicadores_SST_dbo.Campos_Indicadores_SST_ID_CAMPO] FOREIGN KEY([ID_CAMPO])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Campos_Indicadores_SST] ([ID_CAMPO])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Indicadores_SST] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Indicadores_SST_dbo.Campos_Indicadores_SST_ID_CAMPO]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Indicadores_SST]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Indicadores_SST_dbo.Categorias_Indicadores_SST_CATEGORIA_INDICADOR] FOREIGN KEY([CATEGORIA_INDICADOR])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Categorias_Indicadores_SST] ([CATEGORIA_INDICADOR])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Indicadores_SST] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Indicadores_SST_dbo.Categorias_Indicadores_SST_CATEGORIA_INDICADOR]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Indicadores_SST]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Indicadores_SST_dbo.Contratos_ID_CONTRATO] FOREIGN KEY([ID_CONTRATO])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Contratos] ([ID_CONTRATO])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Indicadores_SST] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Indicadores_SST_dbo.Contratos_ID_CONTRATO]
GO
```

Comment: Creo que tu problema es que haces esto  data: '{Ind:'+ JSON.stringify(datosIndicadores) +'}', cuando solo deberia de ser  data: JSON.stringify({
                Ind: datosIndicadores }),

Comment: @EdgarVazquez  Gracias por tú aporte, realice la prueba pero el error pereciste, no sé si sirva de ayuda, pero me muestra este error de `SQL`:


`System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Indicadores_SST_dbo.Campos_Indicadores_SST_ID_CAMPO". The conflict occurred in database "TGI_SARIC", table "dbo.Campos_Indicadores_SST", column 'ID_CAMPO'.
The statement has been terminated.'`

Comment: Pero si estan llegando los valores a tu modelo? eso te esta diciendo de un error en la fk de tu tabla

Comment: @EdgarVazquez Si efectivamente, el controlador, recibe datos, del `Ajax` pero estos valores, todos los valores los muestra en `0` o `NULL` , como tal el `Ajax` creo yo manda los valores pero el controlador no los esta recibiendo me manera correcta, y resulta en un error de `SQL`.

Comment: Pregunto por que le tienes puesto web metodo deberia de ser   [HttpPost] corrige eso y seguimos viendo que puede ser los errores y recuerda que los datos de tu modelo deben de llamarse igual que en el ajax que estas mandando corrige tu pregunta con lo que ya corregiste

Comment: Muchas gracias por tú ayuda, efectivamente la corrección de el parámetro `[HttpPost]` fue efectiva, con la variación de que el data: ` 
 '{Ind:'+ JSON.stringify(datosIndicadores) +'}' ` estaba bien escrito, ahora solo tengo un inconveniente y es que me arroja un error debido a que mi clave principal llega en `0` pero esta se auto incrementa, no sé como deba anexarla en el código y en que parte.

Comment: @idCampo es este parametro verdad? si es asi para que te ponga la respuesta

Comment: @EdgarVazquez no `@idCampo` es una clave foránea, mi clave principal no esta incluida, debido a que pensé que el hecho que se auto incremente, no debía incluirla. mi clave principal se llama `ID_INDICADOR_SST` y solo esta en el modelo.

Comment: Ah esta bien, bueno puedes poner la defenicion de tu tabla para ver como la construiste?

Comment: Claro el modelo es el siguiente, por si es necesario estoy utilizando `Entity Framework` Anexo el código a mi pregunta.

Comment: Me sirve pero me podrias mostrar la de tu tabla Indicadores_SST es decir el CREATE TABLE Indicadores_SST (Campo INT.....)

Comment: @EdgarVazquez, Listo ya anexado el `CREATE` de la tabla Muchas gracias nuevamente por tú ayuda.

Comment: Hola probe el sp con la tabla y si inserta los registros podrias mostrarme exactamente que error te muestra? es que al crear las tablas si me agrego los datos

Comment: Muchas gracias, acabo de revisar, y efectivamente los ingresa, lo que sucede es que mi `AJAX`, lo toma es como un error, aunque si ingresaran los datos correctamente. Muchas gracias por tú ayuda...

Comment: De nada Saludos :D

Comment: @EdgarVazquez Igualmente, gracias por el apoyo a la pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola amigo el detalle esta de lado de tu controlador que tienes [webmetodo] y debe ser [HttpPost]

Y segundo para que no te marque el error en tu sp no mandes la variable ya que no es necesaria

Tu sp quedaria de este modo.

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[agregarIndicador]
     (
         @idCampo int, 
         @categoriaIndicador int,
         @idContrato int,
         @campoPeriodo nvarchar(255) = '',
         @campoValor int
     )
     AS
     BEGIN 
     INSERT INTO Indicadores_SST(ID_CAMPO,CATEGORIA_INDICADOR, ID_CONTRATO, PERIODO, VALOR)
     values (@idCampo, @categoriaIndicador, @idContrato, @campoPeriodo, @campoValor)
     END
```

Y tu controlador quedaria de este modo

```
[HttpPost]
            public void PrimerIndicador(IndicadorSST Ind)
            {
                string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SaricContext"].ConnectionString;
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("agregarIndicador", con);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter()
                    {
                    ParameterName = "@idCampo",
                    Value = Ind.ID_CAMPO
                     });
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter()
                    {
                        ParameterName = "@categoriaIndicador",
                        Value = Ind.CATEGORIA_INDICADOR
                    });
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter()
                    {
                        ParameterName = "@idContrato",
                        Value = Ind.ID_CONTRATO
                    });
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter()
                    {
                        ParameterName = "@campoPeriodo",
                        Value = Ind.PERIODO
                    });
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter()
                    {
                        ParameterName = "@campoValor",
                        Value = Ind.VALOR
                    });
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
```